# SQL Server connection error blocks subsequent connections

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I have a weird use case with how we handle SQL connection in a piece of code. To test this I have created a unit test:

```
var masterBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Server=CHILTERN8564;Integrated Security=SSPI");
var databaseBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(masterBuilder.ConnectionString);
databaseBuilder.InitialCatalog = "CoreIssue";

using (var conDatabase = new SqlConnection(databaseBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
    Assert.Throws<SqlException>(conDatabase.Open); // crash as DB does not exist
}

using (var conMaster = new SqlConnection(masterBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
    // let's create the DB
    conMaster.Open();
    new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE CoreIssue", conMaster).ExecuteNonQuery();
}

using (var conDatabase = new SqlConnection(databaseBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
    // CRASH! even if the DB exists.
    conDatabase.Open();
    new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Bob(name varchar(10))", conDatabase).ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Basically after the first connection throws because the DB does not exist, the last one throws as well, apparently because the DB is in a "broken" state?

If I remove the first `using` block everything works, if I debug and step through the code slowly (waiting a couple of seconds before the last query) everything works.

Any idea on what may cause this behaviour?

Comment: What happens if you put MultipleActiveResultSets=true; in your connection string? Just curious.

Comment: Creating a database in not instantaneous. I think what's happening here is is that your first USING dies because the db doesn't exist, but the second works, but sql server is still creating the data and log files, so it isn't quite ready by the time your third query executes. This would be why everything works if you step slowly through the code.

Comment: I thought about that, but it does not explain why, if the first `using` is not there, everything works... it's the first using that dies which seems to cause the problem...

Answer (score 1):

So MultipleActiveResultSets doesn't help but I found two solutions, if you set:

```
databaseBuilder.Pooling = false;
```

or call

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

So the test would be:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var masterBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(@"Server=localhost\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    var databaseBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(masterBuilder.ConnectionString);
    databaseBuilder.InitialCatalog = "CoreIssue";
    //databaseBuilder.Pooling = false; <- fixes problem

    using (var conDatabase = new SqlConnection(databaseBuilder.ConnectionString))
    {
        Assert.Throws<SqlException>(conDatabase.Open); // crash as DB does not exist
    }

    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools(); //<- also fixes problem

    using (var conMaster = new SqlConnection(masterBuilder.ConnectionString))
    {
        // let's create the DB
        conMaster.Open();
        new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE CoreIssue", conMaster).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (var conDatabase = new SqlConnection(databaseBuilder.ConnectionString))
    {
        // CRASH! even if the DB exists.
        conDatabase.Open();
        new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Bob(name varchar(10))", conDatabase).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Obviously this doesn't really explain why crashed connections are sat around in the pool and reused...